# Removing special characters from strings in a List

Tags: c#, linq, replace

I have a

```
List<string> names = new List<string>{"asa","@!","~!@#$%^tryt","asas**)_+lk"};//just an example...will be populated at run time
List<string> unsupportedCharacters = new List<string> { "~", "!", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*"};
```

Now I want to remove the unsupported characters from each string in the "names" list. I could do it by the foreach loop and checking for each string but I was wondering if there is an better way of achieving this? May be using Linq ?

Question EDIT

How about if I have to replace the unsupportedCharacters  by a single space character..so  "My@@Naame!@%%Is~~Foo" should get converted to "My Name Is Foo"?Ofcourse all the strings are still in the list "names"

Edit 2
Solved it using Regex.Replace()

Comment: This isn't the type of thing that you should spend too much time on. It is a micro-optimization. Either way you will have to look at every character. It will either be an operation of sets of characters O(n*m) or a set of all characters O(n).

Comment: Would you be better to whitelist allowed charachters rather than a black list? Would you accept a snowman? ☃

Comment: @Squid : yes that makes sense and i guess i will incorporate that...btw I would be thrilled if my code accepts snowman one day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`better way`. Not sure. A different way? maybe.

```
var names = new List<string> { "asa", "@!", "~!@#$%^tryt", "asas**)_+lk" };
var unsupportedCharacters = new HashSet<char>("~!#$%^&*");

var newNames = names.Select(n => String.Join("", n.Where(c => !unsupportedCharacters.Contains(c))))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Squid do you have a link showing `new string` is better(in terms of speed, memory requirement etc) than `String.Join`. I can easily change my answer.

Comment: I found this a little faster, but i'm 50/50 as to readability: `var result = names.Select(n => new string(n.Where(ca => !unsupportedCharacters.Contains(ca)).ToArray()));`

Comment: I4V - I did a little benchmark in linqpad, looped over it 1000 times, and the new string was about 15% faster.  OP said that performance wasn't an issue... so decision might be about readability.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you the desired result:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "asa", "@!", "~!@#$%^tryt", "asas**)_+lk" };
List<string> unsupportedCharacters = new List<string> { "~", "!", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*" };
var result = names.Select(str => string.Concat(str.Split(unsupportedCharacters.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));
```